# problem with modal form and bootstrap star rating

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

i use these Libraries in laravel 5.6 in blade view:

jQuery version:
3.2.1

bootstrap-star-rating version:
4.0.2 and 4.0.6

when i clicked show button on any row , modal form opened and the row information is displayed inside a modal form but the value of the Star rating cannot be set

```html
@extends('admin.layout')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.jpg') }}">

    <!-- CSFR token for ajax call -->
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

    <!-- icheck checkboxes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('icheck/square/yellow.css') }}">

    <!-- toastr notifications -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">


     <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">--}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.6/css/star-rating.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.6/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    @section('content')


        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1> {{ trans('labels.Reviews') }} <small>{{ trans('labels.ListingAllReviews') }}...</small> </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('admin/dashboard/this_month') }}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> {{ trans('labels.breadcrumb_dashboard') }}</a></li>
                    <li class="active">{{ trans('labels.Reviews') }}</li>
                </ol>
            </section>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">

                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">{{ trans('labels.ListingAllReviews') }} </h3>
                            </div>

                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i> All the current Reviews/Comments</li>
                                            <a href="#" class="add-modal"><li>Add a Review/Comment</li></a>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="postTable" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th valign="middle">#</th>
                                                <th>Customer</th>
                                                <th>Rating</th>
                                                <th>Comment</th>
                                                <th>Published?</th>
                                                <th>Last updated</th>
                                                <th>Actions</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            @foreach($posts as $indexKey => $post)
                                                <tr class="item{{$post->id}} @if($post->is_approved) warning @endif">
                                                    <td class="col1">{{ $indexKey+1 }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$post->customer_name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$post->rating}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$post->comment}}</td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="published" id="" data-id="{{$post->id}}" @if ($post->is_approved) checked @endif></td>
                                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post->updated_at)->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button class="show-modal btn btn-success" data-id="{{$post->id}}" data-rating="{{$post->rating}}" data-customer_name="{{$post->customer_name}}" data-comment="{{$post->comment}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Show</button>
                                                        <button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" data-id="{{$post->id}}" data-rating="{{$post->rating}}" data-customer_name="{{$post->customer_name}}" data-comment="{{$post->comment}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button>
                                                        <button class="delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$post->id}}" data-rating="{{$post->rating}}" data-customer_name="{{$post->customer_name}}" data-comment="{{$post->comment}}">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

                                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                                            {{$posts->links('vendor.pagination.default')}}
                                        </div>

                                    </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->


                <!-- Modal form to show a post****************************************************************************************************** -->
                <div id="showModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_show" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="customer_name">Customer:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="customer_name_show" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rating">Rating:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="rating_show" disabled>
                                            <input type="name" class="form-control rating rating-loading" id="rating_show1" name="rating_show1" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Comment:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment_show" cols="40" rows="5" disabled></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Modal form to edit a form****************************************************************************************************** -->
                <div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_edit" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="customer_name">Customer:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name_edit">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rating">Rating:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating_edit" autofocus>
                                            <p class="errorTitle text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Comment:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment_edit" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
                                            <p class="errorContent text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> Edit
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    // Show a post***********************************************************************
                    $(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
                        $('.modal-title').text('Show');
                        $('#id_show').val($(this).data('id'));
                        $('#customer_name_show').val($(this).data('customer_name'));
                        $('#rating_show').val($(this).data('rating'));
                        $('#rating_show1').val($(this).data('rating'));
                        $('#rating_show1').rating('update', $(this).data('rating'));
                        $('#showModal').modal('show');

                    });


                    // Edit a post***********************************************************************
                    $(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
                        $('.modal-title').text('Edit');
                        $('#id_edit').val($(this).data('id'));
                        $('#customer_name_edit').val($(this).data('customer_name'));
                        $('#rating_edit').val($(this).data('rating'));
                        $('#comment_edit').val($(this).data('comment'));
                        id = $('#id_edit').val();
                        $('#editModal').modal('show');
                    });
                    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'PUT',
                            url: 'reviewsx/' + id,
                            data: {
                                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                                'id': $("#id_edit").val(),
                                'customer_name': $('#customer_name_edit').val(),
                                'rating': $('#rating_edit').val(),
                                'comment': $('#comment_edit').val()
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('.errorCustomer').addClass('hidden');
                                $('.errorRating').addClass('hidden');
                                $('.errorComment').addClass('hidden');

                                if ((data.errors)) {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $('#editModal').modal('show');
                                        toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                                    }, 500);

                                    if (data.errors.customer_name) {
                                        $('.errorCustomer_name').removeClass('hidden');
                                        $('.errorCustomer_name').text(data.errors.customer_name);
                                    }
                                    if (data.errors.rating) {
                                        $('.errorRating').removeClass('hidden');
                                        $('.errorRating').text(data.errors.rating);
                                    }
                                    if (data.errors.comment) {
                                        $('.errorComment').removeClass('hidden');
                                        $('.errorComment').text(data.errors.comment);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    toastr.success('Successfully updated Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                                    // $('.item' + data.id).replaceWith("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td class='col1'>" + data.id + "</td><td> " + data.title + "</td><td>" + data.content + "</td><td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' class='edit_published' data-id='" + data.id + "'></td><td>Right now</td><td><button class='show-modal btn btn-success' data-id='" + data.id +                                                 "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Show</button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-title='" + data.title + "' data-content='" + data.content + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
                                    $('.item' + data.id).replaceWith("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td class='col1'>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.customer_name +"</td><td>" + data.rating + "</td><td>" + data.comment + "</td><td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' class='edit_published' data-id='" + data.id + "'></td><td>Right now</td><td><button class='show-modal btn btn-success' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-customer_name='" + data.customer_name + "' data-rating='" + data.rating + "' data-comment='" + data.comment + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Show</button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-customer_name='" + data.customer_name + "' data-rating='" + data.rating + "' data-comment='" + data.comment + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-customer_name='" + data.customer_name + "' data-rating='" + data.rating + "' data-comment='" + data.comment + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");

                                    if (data.is_approved) {
                                        $('.edit_published').prop('checked', true);
                                        $('.edit_published').closest('tr').addClass('warning');
                                    }
                                    $('.edit_published').iCheck({
                                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-yellow',
                                        radioClass: 'iradio_square-yellow',
                                        increaseArea: '20%'
                                    });
                                    $('.edit_published').on('ifToggled', function(event) {
                                        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('warning');
                                    });
                                    $('.edit_published').on('ifChanged', function(event){
                                        id = $(this).data('id');
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: "{{ URL::route('changeStatus') }}",
                                            data: {
                                                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                                                'id': id
                                            },
                                            success: function(data) {
                                                // empty
                                            },
                                        });
                                    });
                                    $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                                        $(this).html(index+1);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

```html
                <!-- /.row -->
            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->


        </div>

    @endsection

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the rating field value like star in modal form when I click on the show button

same for edit form

[image: screen shot of my page]

Comment: you can set rating value in button data attribute like *** data-rating="4" *** . And when you click on show button then you can get the value like  " $(this).data('rating');".

Comment: As you can see in the codes I've done this before `                                                        <button class="show-modal btn btn-success" data-id="{{$post->id}}" data-rating="{{$post->rating}}" data-customer_name="{{$post->customer_name}}" data-comment="{{$post->comment}}">
` and then in **javascript** , i set it `$('#rating_show1').val($(this).data('rating'));` but it does not work

Comment: Can you please console.log($(this).data('rating')) value before 
 $('#rating_show1').val($(this).data('rating')); .

Comment: mukesh, The console display rating value of each row correctly